# ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'imlementation()'

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-10.0

My app is not working after I updated my android phone to Android 10. So I migrated my app to androidx. Now I am trying to update my gradle from 2.3.1 to 3.5.1.

This is my build.gradle(Project:) file -

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
```

My build.gradle(Project:) file is -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "....."
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    imlementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation files('....')
    implementation files('....')
    implementation files('....')
    implementation files('....')
}
```

This is the Error I get -

ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'imlementation()'
Possible causes:

> The project '.....' may be using a version of the
>   Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g.
>   'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0). Upgrade plugin to version 3.5.1 and
>   sync project
>
> The project '...' may be using a version of
>   Gradle that does not contain the method. Open Gradle wrapper file
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin

I am new to android development. I am using android studio.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You made a typo in your first `implementation` declaration. `imlementation` -> `implementation`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `imlementation`

to

```
implementation
```

Comment: @ZabojCampula and why this does not provide an answer ? It is the solution.

Comment: I am sorry, that was my review fault. I just saw the answer and did not realize that the only problem is a simple typo.